# Sourcetree 2.7.x not using password from Keychain

Tags: macos, atlassian-sourcetree

The latest version of Sourcetree for Mac as of 19 September 2018 is 2.7.6. You can see in the [Sourcetree 2.7.6 changelog](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/update/releasenotes/2.7.6.html) that Keychain issues have plagued the Mac application for years.

If I allow Sourcetree to save the remote password (e.g. Github, Bitbucket) in the Keychain, all attempts to connect to that service fail. If I then check the account settings in Sourcetree, the account password has changed to the Keychain password (you can only tell that if they have different lengths).

> Sourcetree > Preferences... > Accounts > Edit... > (Contents of "Password:" field)

The only workaround I know so far is to delete the Sourcetree entry for that Git service from the Keychain, and prevent Sourcetree from saving the password every time it asks. Unfortunately, this means I have to reenter the password every time, and untick "Store Password In Keychain".

[image: Password prompt]

[image: Keychain prompt]

I expect the only solution is to wait for an update that fixes the issue, but this question is to provide a canonical reference.

Answer (score 2):

try run `ssh-add` in your terminal, it solved problem for me

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found 2 options:

1. Manually add this line into the `.gitconfig` file. Found under Repository Settings -> Advanced Tab -> Edit Config File (or manually edit)

```
    [credential]
        helper = store
```

2. run this command:

   `git config --global credential.helper store`